# How do you get the selected object from a YUI 3 Autocomplete object?

Tags: yui, yui3

I am attempting to get the array object from the autocomplete code to be able to use a string stored in the array. When I perform the on change action, I can show a plain alert, but am unable to get the array from the autocomplete code. I use the resultTextLocator successfully in the same autocomplete code, but I use it to put a person's first and last name in the text box associated with the autocomplete code. I am attempting to get the person's user id that is also stored in the array. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to the [select](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/AutoCompleteList.html#event_select) event & take a look at the result object. Assuming that data passed into AutoComplete has the id it should be accessible there.

Comment: I still can't get this to display correctly... Maybe I am doing something wrong. [Click here for a link to an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/LJRAY/18/) Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was saying about the result object. I [forked your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tivac/qeCWa/2/) & it now shows both possible ways of getting the selected item.

Comment: The above comment by Tivac worked for me. Thank you so much. Apparently I didn't understand exactly what you were saying. Thank you again!